# Can CListCtrl use OnMeasureItem() method?

Tags: mfc, listview

I want to change item's height and width according to a slider, but as far as I know, there's no measureitem method as CListBox. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All items in CListCtrl have to have the same size. I believe you can use OnMeasureItem in the container that holds the CListCtrl, but it won't be called for each item, but only once for the entire control.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to attach an **image list** to the **CListCtrl**. The rows will then take on a height based on the height of the image list.